# Cannot insert document into collection

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following method :

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection;
...
Document query = new Document();
query.put("uuid", uuid);
query.put("gems", "$exists");
Document document = collection.find(query).first();
if(document == null) {
    System.out.println("Not found");
    document = new Document();
    document.put("uuid", uuid);
    document.put("gems", 0L);
    collection.insertOne(document);
}
```

Now, the collection is there, I checked in Mongo, but for some reason the document is never inserted.
I run:

```
db.(collection).find()
```

And get no output.

The document is never found, I don't know if my query is correct, but the document is never inserted. This is done with a clean install of MongoDB running on localhost. MongoDB shows as connected and no errors are thrown. 
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work, it fixes the insert and finding method:

```
Document document = collection.find(Filters.eq("uuid", uuid)).first();
if (document == null) {
    document = new Document("uuid", uuid);
    document.put("gems", 0L);
    collection.insertOne(document);
}
```